# Python web app with background worker thread

Tags: python, flask

Requirements:

- Define "job" that has start time *t*, batch size *s*, invocation interval *i* and *list* that should be processed
- Starting with time *t* grab next *s* items from *list* every *i* seconds and process it
- Job can be paused and resumed (user should be able to tell the job to stop grabbing new list items for processing)

Flask will be used for web app. Obviously, I need some background process/thread that will periodically execute processing code.

Since the state will be in persisted to database, simplest approach that I can think of is to define a cronjob that will periodically execute python script that checks for active jobs and performs the processing.

Any suggestion on how to design this using only python?

- Start another python process that will periodically check and execute active jobs?
- Spawn a worker thread from Flask?
- ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you employ a queuing mechanism like Redis or RabbitMQ. Flask would act as a producer and and your "worker" would consume and process.

Setting either of these tools up is far less daunting that you might expect.

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install redis
```

Your flask app acts as a producer

```
>>> from redis import Redis
>>> r = Redis()
>>> r.lpush('task_queue', 'task1')
1L
```

And your "worker" consumes and processes asynchronously:

```
>>> r.rpop('task_queue')
'task1'
```

Comment: I was more interested in how to implement *consumer* and integrate it with web app. Any thoughts on that topic?